# Is all the features added in java 9 &10 are now part of java 11?

Tags: java, java-11

As known java 9 and java 10 have short term support and java 11 is long term support version.
If we move our project from java 8 to java 11, will all the features added in java 9 & 10  will be available in it.

Comment: Any feature in particular you're thinking about?

Comment: That's how versioning works; all features from 1 to 10 are in 11, unless explicitly marked "deprecated, for removal".

Comment: Federico klez Culloca : For a particular feature i can check the api of java11 if its present or deprecated. But wanted to know about all features, as checking this will take time. So have raised this question to get a straight answer, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

## Release notes

Please read through the [*JDK 11 Release Notes*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-11-relnote.html).

All the [deprecated features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software) from the previous versions of Java are mentioned there.

## Deprecated features

Specific deprecated features are mentioned here https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Refer these docs too https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/v9-deprecated-features.html

Apart from these deprecated features you can use all the other features from previous versions of Java.

Comment: Even deprecated features can be used if you really need to, because deprecated just means you shouldn't use it, and - if marked as for removal - might be removed in a future version.